# Do i need to stop MusicPlayerController first before i play to next song in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

In my app , i have to play songs from iPod Library with `MPMusicPlayerContrller's` `iPodMusicPlayer`.

I just want to know , in my app , first song is playing from Album and when i want to play another song from Playlists that selected from `UITableView` do i need to use stop function `[self.player stop];` before change next songs?

Or i can directly play without stop current playing song?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to stop.my question is "Why to stop?". no,never nothing, there is no need of stop.
ios already given you facility of playing new song from playlist through the properties.

if you stops it & again play it,its just wastage of execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably use `skipToNextItem` or `skipToPreviousItem` it's perfectly legit to use them directly.

Documentation for [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: sorry for my incomplete question. i mean my now playing song is from Albums , and next songs is from playlist that selected from UITableView. thz bro

Comment: I see. If you're not using MPMediaQuery/MPMediaItemCollection at all you might want to consider using AVPlayer instead.